# Hazelcast JCache Listener is being serialized?

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, jcache

I have two spring-boot services that talk to each other through a caching layer ( because of reasons not related with the issue ). I am using JCache (jsr-107) api to abstract away the actual cache provider, in this case Hazelcast. I am manually registering a few cache event listeners (update, create and delete ) and consuming those events to perform some actions.

A simple use case would be `service A` consuming a `CacheEntryUpdatedListener` event that `service B` created by pushing some data to a particular cache. When I start `service A`. it's starts correctly and creates it's own Hazelcast cluster node. When `service B` is attempting to join that Hazelcast node, it finds it correctly but then gets immediately disconnected, and I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException:c.i.c.e.i.b.ws.m.cache.listener.MarketStateRefreshListener`,  MarketStateRefreshListener is a cache event listener, why would Hazelcast attempt to persist it, those listeners make no sense outside of `service B`, there is no point in them being saved to the IMDG ? Am I fundamentally missunderstanding how Hazelcast clusters work ?

Here is the hazelcast config ( used by both services ):

```
<hazelcast
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.10.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <group>
        <name>cache_group_name</name>
    </group>

    <network>
        <port>5701</port>
        <join>
            <multicast/>
        </join>
    </network>

    <cache name="cache_name_1">
        <!--<management-enabled>true</management-enabled>-->
        <!--<backup-count>3</backup-count>-->
    </cache>
    <cache name="cache_name_2"/>
    <cache name="cache_name_3"/>
</hazelcast>
```

I am using JCache so the update cache events are handled by a `javax.cache.event.CacheEntryUpdatedListener` instance . One such a class is :

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MarketSummaryStateUpdatedListener implements CacheEntryUpdatedListener<String, MarketSummaryState> {

    private CacheEventService eventService;

    @Override
    public void onUpdated(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends String, ? extends MarketSummaryState>> events)
            throws CacheEntryListenerException {
        events.forEach( event -> {
           eventService.fireEvent(MARKET_STATE, event.getEventType(), EventData.of(event.getValue()));
        });
    }

}
```

The even listener is a spring @Component and so is `private CacheEventService eventService;`

Regards,
Peter

Comment: can you share the config? I have a sample app as you described & it works fine.

Comment: HI, I've edited the question.

Comment: Can u also share how you defined the EntryUpdatedListener?

Comment: the exception you shared says `MarketStateRefreshListener` but you shared another listener. Can you please share that one as well. Also, I couldn't see how you register the listener to the Cache, not in the config. Can you share the code/config block for that as well?

Comment: It's the same class I just changed the name.

Comment: Can you please show how you are registering `MarketSummaryStateUpdatedListener` to the cache?